# How to treat corrupted text as data in Python 3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, io, character-encoding

my code is reading lines from csv files with corrupted text - mix of ascii and oct. And I'm trying to recover an original text in UTF-8 but I'm missing something obvious.

```
line = "Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala" #Tomáš Vala
print(a)
TomÃ¡Å¡ Vala  #incorrect
```

If I type the line manually in command line the result is correct:

```
>>> a = b"Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala" 
>>> a = a.decode("utf-8")
'Tomáš Vala'  # correct
```

But how to print the line as it is already in bytes?

```
>>> a = "Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala" 
>>> print(a)
TomÃ¡Å¡ Vala  #incorrect

>>> b = bytes(a, 'utf=8')
>>> b.decode('utf=8')
'TomÃ¡Å¡ Vala' #incorrect
```

Comment: Your *actual data* contains `\ddd` sequences? That's a literal backslash and three digits. That's not the same thing as using `\ddd` in a Python string literal, where those sequences have meaning. Can you give a sample of your actual data instead?

Comment: Your data can be defined in a Python string literal as `r"Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala"`, note the `r` at the start, or by doubling the backslashes.

Comment: The file contains lines in format:
Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala, V\303\241lec, 1.1.1984,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate all literal backslash escape sequences. You could do this with a regular expression:

```
import re

seq = re.compile(br'\\[0-8]{3}')
decode_seq = lambda m: bytes([int(m.group()[1:], 8)])
def repair(data):
    return seq.sub(decode_seq, data)
```

This decodes data in a `bytes` object:

```
>>> broken = rb"Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala"
>>> repair(broken)
b'Tom\xc3\xa1\xc5\xa1 Vala'
>>> repair(broken).decode('utf8')
'Tomáš Vala'
```

To wrap an existing file, you'd have to implement a [`io.BufferedIOBase` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) to translate bytes as you read:

```
import re
from io import BufferedIOBase

class OctetEscapeDecodeWrapper(BufferedIOBase):
    def __init__(self, buffer):
        # we wrap a buffer, not a raw object, so don't use raw here.
        self._buffer = buffer
        self._remainder = b''

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def detach(self):
        result, self._buffer = self._buffer, None
        return result

    def _decode(self, data, 
                _seq=re.compile(br'\\[0-8]{3}'), 
                _decode=lambda m: bytes([int(m.group()[1:], 8)])):
        return _seq.sub(_decode, data)

    def read1(self, size=-1):
        self._remainder, data = b'', self._remainder + self._buffer.read1(size)
        trail = data.rfind(b'\\', -3)
        if trail > -1 and all(48 <= data[i] <= 57 for i in range(trail + 1, len(data))):
            # data ends \dd or \d, retain until next read so we can decode then
            self._remainder, data = data[trail:], data[:trail]
        return self._decode(data)

    read = read1

    def readinto1(self, b):
        data = self.read1(len(b))
        b[:len(data)] = data
        return len(data)

    readinto = readinto1
```

This can be used to wrap an existing binary file to decode your data on the fly:

```
import csv
from io import TextIOWrapper

with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as binary:
    text = TextIOWrapper(OctetEscapeDecodeWrapper(binary), encoding='utf8')
    reader = csv.reader(text)
    for row in reader:
        # ...
```

Demo:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper
>>> sample = BytesIO(b'Tom\303\241\305\241 Vala, V\303\241lec, 1.1.1984,')
>>> b = OctetEscapeDecodeWrapper(sample)
>>> t = TextIOWrapper(b, encoding='utf8')
>>> import csv
>>> next(csv.reader(t))
['Tomáš Vala', ' Válec', ' 1.1.1984', '']
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But as I'm new to python and programming itself, I have to catch first what have you done here. Thx

Comment: @Panther: I added a decoding wrapper to decode file data on the fly.

Comment: Than you very much for your generous help. I learned something new today.